# How do I count the number of documents (onWrite) and save the counter into a specific path via Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

With my code I can count the number of documents in Firebase Realtime database but I need them to have a counter for each groupId which is then saved in a different path for each groupId.

**Here the path of the documents I am counting**

messages/{groupId}

**I want to save it here, each counter for its own groupId**

totalmessages/groupId

```
 exports.messageCounter = functions.database.ref('/messages/{groupId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
   const data = change.after.val();
   const group = data.groupId;
   const count = Object.keys(data).length;
      return admin.database().ref('totalmessages/'+group).child('_count').set(count);
 });
```

Currently code returns:

[image]

also he overwrites the "_Count" with new data and do not create several trees.

Comment: What does your code do now that doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @DougStevenson please see updated Question.

Comment: Looks like `group` is undefined.  Also your question says that you want to write to a node called "messageCounter", but your code is writing to "totalmessages".  What do you really want to accomplish here?

Comment: @DougStevenson Regarding "messageCounter" and "totalmessages" - just realized and edited Question, code is correct for that. 
How can I define "Group"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get the groupId wildcard from your function invocation, you will want to use the context for that:

```
const group = context.params.groupId;
```

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works great